# I want to send POST request from arduino to mysql workbench and save the value

Tags: java, c++, spring, post, arduino

I have already created api in the spring boot application. my arduino code returns -1 (httpcode) in the arduino log. So what my api is to POST data is http://localhost:8080/ApparelProject/device/saveDistance/{value}
following is my arduino code.

arduino code

```
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h> 

// defines pins numbers
const int trigPin = 2;  //D4
const int echoPin = 0;  //D3

// defines variables
long duration;
int distance;

void setup() {
pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
Serial.begin(9600); // Starts the serial communication
}

void loop() {
// Clears the trigPin
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(2);

// Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

// Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

// Calculating the distance
distance= duration*0.034/2;
// Prints the distance on the Serial Monitor
Serial.print("Distance: ");
Serial.println(distance);
   HTTPClient http;
    http.begin("http://localhost:8080/ApparelProject/device/saveDistance");
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
  int httpCode = http.POST("125");

    Serial.println(httpCode);
       http.end();

   /* HTTPClient http;
       String url = "localhost:8080/ApparelProject/device/saveDistance/"+String(distance);
       Serial.println(url);
       //localhost:8080/ApparelProject/device/saveDistance/20000    
        http.begin(url);

        //POST method
       int httpCode = http.GET();
       Serial.println(httpCode);
       http.end();*/
delay(2000);
}
```

Spring code

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/saveDistance/{distance}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveDistance(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable(value ="distance") String distance) {
        System.out.println(distance);
        return distanceimpl.saveDistance(distance);
    }
```

Comment: can you please share the api code as well?

Comment: @SupunDharmarathne

Comment: Have you tested the endpoint alone?

Comment: yeah i did is arduino code has an error?

Comment: see my modified answer below

Comment: i tried to send data from the data cable to my localhost! do i need to connect to wifi to send data to my local host

Comment: Is this connection working fine?

Comment: You can use the localhost of your machine when your arduino and PC is connected to the same network. But you need to get your PC's IP address by doing CMD check

Comment: ok thanks i will get back to you!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
HTTPClient http;
http.begin("http://localhost:8080/ApparelProject/device/saveDistance/125");
http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
int httpCode = http.POST();

Serial.println(httpCode);
http.end();
```

Try something like this to ensure the connection is working.

```
    void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(4000);   //Delay needed before calling the WiFi.begin

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password); 

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { //Check for the connection
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }

  Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");

}
```

Comment: did try it didn't work is there another method to send a post request ?

Comment: yeah http code in -1 i have included my arduino code and my controller code

Answer (score 1):

Try this...
You will needed `ArduinoJSON` Library for this.

```
StaticJsonBuffer<300> JSONbuffer;   //Declaring static JSON buffer
  JsonObject& JSONencoder = JSONbuffer.createObject();

  JSONencoder["value"] = "125"; //or some variable
  char JSONmessageBuffer[300];
  JSONencoder.prettyPrintTo(JSONmessageBuffer, sizeof(JSONmessageBuffer));

  HTTPClient http;    //Declare object of class HTTPClient

  http.begin("http://Your_PC_IP_Address:8080/ApparelProject/device/saveDistance");      //Specify request destination
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");  //Specify content-type header

  int httpCode = http.POST(JSONmessageBuffer);   //Send the request
  String payload = http.getString();                  //Get the response payload
```

It gives you this kind of JSON array.

```
{
   value:"125"
}
```

According to that change your Backend API sorry I don't have much knowledge about Spring Endpoint.